# Parámetro (Parameters.Add) en ASP.NET MVC SqlServer

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

Bien, esto es lo que quiero hacer. La página principal, (Index), tiene una caja de texto y un botón. El usuario, debe ingresar un dato numérico. En este caso su número de título, por ejemplo: 111111. Luego, al presionar al botón, se deben mostrar todos los datos del usuario. 
Este es el formulario(Index):

```
<form id="form">
        <div>
            @using (Html.BeginForm())
            {
                <p>
                    Título: @Html.TextBox("buscar")
                    <input type="submit" value="Filtrar" /><br />
                    <input type="button" value="Imprimir" onclick="window.print()" />
                </p>
            }
        </div>
        <div>
            <table border="1">
                @foreach (var item in Model)
                {
                <tr>
                    <th scope="row" abbr="Suscriptor">Suscriptor: </th>
                    <td>

                        <b>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Apellido) @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Nombre)</b>
                    </td>
                    <td>Título: @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Titulo)</td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.ActionLink("Ver detalles en PDF", "PrintPartialViewToPdf", new { id = item.Titulo })
                    </td>
                </tr>
                }
            </table>
        </div>
    </form>
```

Este es el modelo, donde realizo la consulta:

```
public List<Cuotas> cargarDatos(double? tit)
        {
            List<Cuotas> salida = new List<Cuotas>();
            using ("string"))
            {
                conn.Open();
                SqlCommand comand = new SqlCommand("SELECT titulo, apellido +', '+nombre,cuotas FROM datosSuscripto WHERE titulo = @tit", conn);
                var param = comand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@tit", SqlDbType.Float));
                param.Value = tit;
                using (SqlDataReader dr = comand.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (dr.Read())
                    {
                        double titulo = Convert.ToDouble(dr.GetDouble(0));
                        string nombre = dr.GetString(1);
                        double cuota = Convert.ToDouble(dr.GetDouble(2));
                        Cuotas p = new Cuotas(titulo, nombre, cuota);
                        salida.Add(p);
                    }
                }
                conn.Close();
            }
            return salida;
        }
```

Este es el controlador del Index:

```
public ActionResult Index(double? consulta)
        {
            ConexionSQL cn = new ConexionSQL();
            return View(cn.cargarDatos(consulta));
        }
```

Y este es el error:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'The parameterized query '(@tit float)SELECT titulo, apellido +', '+nombre,cuotas FROM dat' expects the parameter '@tit', which was not supplied.'
```

¡Alguna idea de como solucionarlo? Espero haberme dado a entender

Comment: P/D: por sino se entendió, quiero que la pantalla principal solo tenga el textbox y el botón. Debe iniciar con eso

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba a asignar el parámetro de esta manera:

```
comand.Parameters.Add("@tit", SqlDbType.Float).Value = tit;
// param.Value = tit; Esto no hace falta
```

Por otra parte, debes comprobar también si el parámetro `double? tit` esté llegando a NULL.

Si es así, debes asignar un `DBNull.Value` directamente:

```
if (tit == null) 
{
    comand.Parameters.Add("@tit", SqlDbType.Float).Value = DBNull.Value;
}
else  
{
    comand.Parameters.Add("@tit", SqlDbType.Float).Value = tit;
}
```

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, he hecho como mencionas y sigue saliendo el mismo error

Comment: @FranqoBalsamo: Has comprobado si el parámetro `tit` te está llegando a NULL?.

Comment: Gracias, era eso. Solo que ahora pasa que al ingresar valores, no me muestra nada jaja